# Как заполнить двумерный массив единицами с заданной вероятностью?

Tags: javascript, массивы, теория-вероятностей

Есть 3 поля: 2 из них это количество ячеек по горизонтали и вертикали. При их заполнении, формируется матрица с указанной размерностью, заполненная 0. В 3 поле задается вероятность, с которой матрица заполнится единицами.

[image: Матрица на Vue.js]

```js
var h = 10,
  v = 10,
  p = 0.5;

arr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < v; i++) {

  arr[i] = [];

  for (var j = 0; j < h; j++) {
    arr[i][j] = 0 //присваивать 0 или 1 с заданной вероятностью p
  }
}

console.log(arr);
```

Задать через стандартную функцию random(min, max) не достаточно будет, нужно к ней как-то еще привязать коэффициент из 3-го поля.

Есть у кого-то идеи, как можно реализовать такой алгоритм или что почитать по этой теме.

Comment: Какова точная формулировка задачи? Если вероятность относится к каждой отдельной ячейке, то ответ @Stepan даст то, что нужно. Однако стоит знать, что при этом плотность заполнения всей таблицы не обязательно будет 15% (эта величина будет подчиняться биномиальному распределению)

Comment: Вероятность заполнения 1 указывается для всей матрицы

Comment: т.е. для тех же 15% в матрица 10*10 должна содержать всего 15 `1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вероятность относится к каждой отдельной ячейке, то генерация 1 с вероятностью p, как показано в ответах, даст то, что нужно.

Однако стоит знать, что при этом плотность заполнения всей таблицы не обязательно будет p (например, 15%)  - эта величина будет подчиняться биномиальному распределению.

Для гарантии, что заполнение таблицы будет именно `p` (или максимально близкое к заданной величине `p` значение, выражаемое целочисленной дробью), то можно сгенерировать массив размером `v*h`, содержащий именно `p*v*h` единиц, затем перенести содержимое в таблиццу, используя подход, аналогичный тасованию  [Фишера-Йетса](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%99%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D0%B0).

[Код:](https://playcode.io/129485?tabs=console&script.js&output) (всегда даёт ровно 8 единиц)

```
var h = 4;
var v = 4;
var p = 0.5;
var n = h * v;
var a = [];
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) 
   a.push((i < n*p) ? 1 : 0);

var arr = [];

var last = n;
for (var i = 0; i < v; i++) {
   arr[i] = [];
   for (var j = 0; j < h; j++) {
      var rr = Math.floor(Math.random() * last);
      arr[i].push(a[rr]);
      a[rr] = a[--last];
  }
}
console.log(arr);
[ [ 0, 1, 0, 0 ], [ 1, 1, 0, 1 ], [ 0, 1, 0, 1 ], [ 0, 1, 0, 1 ] ]
```

Comment: спасибо за хороший ответ и ссылку, буду изучать сегодня. Учить надо алгоритмы лучше все-таки в первую очередь. Можете посоветовать пару хороших на ваш взгляд книг или других источников по алгоритмам, если есть в арсенале такие?

Comment: Попроще - Левитин. Посерьезнее Седжвик (с рабочим кодом), Кормен, Скиена.

Answer (score 0):

Я точно в ответе не уверен. Возможно, такой ответ вам подойдет.

Пример.

```js
var h = 10,
  v = 10,
  p = 0.15;

arr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < v; i++) {

  arr[i] = [];

  for (var j = 0; j < h; j++) {
    arr[i][j] = Math.random() <= p ? 1 : 0;
  }
}

console.log(arr.reduce((r, a) => r + a.filter(f => f == 1).length, 0));
console.log(arr.map(m => m.join(' ')));
```

Answer (score 0):

Тут есть пара вариантов. Более менее честный:

```
<script>
    function getRandomInt(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }

var h = 10,
  v = 10,
  p = 0.15;

arr = [];
var count = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < v; i++) {

  arr[i] = [];

  for (var j = 0; j < h; j++) {
  if (getRandomInt(0, 100)< p*100){
    arr[i][j] = 1; //присваивать 0 или 1 с заданной вероятностью p
    count ++;
    } else {
    arr[i][j] = 0; //присваивать 0 или 1 с заданной вероятностью p
    }
  }
}

console.log(arr);
console.log(count);
</script>
```

Если вам надо прямо чтобы было ровно, то ваша вероятность, тогда надо просто контролировать, сколько единиц должно быть в каждой строке массива.